# Rx filter by criterion and n values after criterion

Tags: c#, .net, linq, system.reactive

#### Filter by criterion only

```
changes.Where(p => Evaluate(p)).Subscribe(p => { // Do something });
```

*But how could you make it so that you get the criterion value and n values after the criterion is fulfilled (and these n values do not have to match the evaluation criterion)?*

- e.g. i would like to subscribe to a stream that returns on `Evaluate(p)` and one value after that (and then starts to evaluate `p` again)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please take a look on [SkipWhile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb549288.aspx) and [Take](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb503062.aspx) extension methods of [IEnumerable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb341635.aspx). You can try following code:

```
changes.SkipWhile(change => Evaluate(change) == false).Take(n).Subscribe(change => { /* do something */ });
```

***Edit***

New code to take all matching items from sequence with `n` items' tail (without retrieving items repeatedly)

```
// Let's assume elements in the sequence are of type Change
int i = 0;
Func<Change, bool> evaluateWithTail = change =>
{
    if (i <= 0 || i > n)
    {
        i = Evaluate(change) ? 1 : 0;
    }
    else
    {
        i++;
    }

    return i > 0;
}
// Please note delegate is specified as parameter directly - without lambda expression
changes.Where(evaluateWithTail).Subscribe(change => { /* do something */ });
```

Comment: i realized it does not work fully, because "these n values do not have to match the evaluation criterion" and the `SkipWhile` at the start helps with the first occurrence only?

Comment: @Cel Please take a look on updated code. It was already added `Where(change => Evaluate(change) == false)` just after `SkipWhile` by the time when you posted your first comment. Please note that in order to take first matching value you will most likely will need to make separate call of First method.

Comment: I saw the updated code, but that does still not work fully because i need the n values to be returned even if Evaluate(change) == true, but the Where clause blocks that i.e. the n values after the critical evaluation should not be evaluated at all and then the critical evaluation should be reset..

Comment: @Cel Could you please confirm whether I correctly realized your question before I add next edit? Am I right that you need to retrieve first matching value together with following n values - regardless of whether following values match or not?

Comment: I confirm. And this should continue, so after the first matching value with subsequent n values are returned then a new (second) match should be looked for and when match is found then the match with subsequent n values should be returned, and so on for more matches.

Comment: @Cel Looks like you need a tricky selection of items from sequence and For that sake it feels natural to use tricky evaluation function - please see edit in my post.

Comment: after some testing should it not be: `if (i <= 0 || i >= n)
{                                                                               i = Evaluate(change) ? 1 : 0;
        } else 
        {
i++;}`

Answer (score 3):

Here's another implementation that's a bit shorter:

```
var filtered = source
  .SkipWhile( x => !Criteria(x) )
  .Take(3)
  .Repeat()
```

Comment: what is the effect of .Repeat() here - does it re-push the first 3 values that are taken? if that is the case then this will get stuck in the past so to speak and stop evaluating values pushed to `source` after a short while, which is not what im after? or does .Repeat() here essentially reset .SkipWhile() and .Take() which are then re-evaluated on new values?

Comment: When I tested it it gave the desired behaviour. The Repeat takes it back to the SkipWhile.

Comment: @MatthewFinlay Could you please point to documentation of Repeat method (all I found is [Repeat](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb348899.aspx) method of [IEnumerable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb341635.aspx) - it seems like method that I found is slightly different). Thanks in advance.

Comment: this is very neat then! i might have to steal the answer from Andrii, but ill upvote for now :) heres the link to the overload http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh229428%28v=vs.103%29.aspx

Comment: The official documentation is [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh211952%28v=vs.103%29.aspx), I swear I read a good example on a blog but can't seem to find it.

Comment: The `Repeat` overload used here will keep using `Concat` to concatenate the source sequence to itself indefinitely. As long as `source` is a hot observable it will "do the right thing", i.e. when the `SkipWhile` is repeated it will continue consuming the source sequence after what was "taken" by `Take`.

Comment: Could you please explain why `Repeat` is not applied to results of `Take` which is right before it and is instead applied to results of `SkipWhile` which is one position far from `Repeat`? (has not found points to that in documentation)

Comment: When Repeat is called, it goes back as far as it can and asks for the Observable again. This means that if you're using a cold observable the sequence will be restarted. If you want to reproduce the hot observable behaviour with a cold observable, then you'll need to put a Subject in the middle and call sub.OnNext and then subscribe to that. This is all just based on my experimenting.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you can create an Rx operator by combining existing operators because essentially what you want is to use the `Where` operator, but after it matches you want to "turn it off" for the next N elements. OK, apparently you can by using the `Repeat` operator and that proves how composable Rx is.

Anyway, you can also create a new operator using best practices for creating your own Rx operator:

```
static class Extensions {

  public static IObservable<T> WhereThenTake<T>(
    this IObservable<T> source,
    Predicate<T> predicate,
    Int32 count
  ) {
    if (source == null)
      throw new ArgumentNullException("source");
    if (predicate == null)
      throw new ArgumentNullException("predicate");
    if (count < 0)
      throw new ArgumentException("count");
    return Observable.Create<T>(
      observer => {
        var finished = false;
        var n = 0;
        var disposable = source.Subscribe(
          x => {
            if (!finished) {
              if (n > 0) {
                observer.OnNext(x);
                n -= 1;
              }
              else if (predicate(x)) {
                n = count;
                observer.OnNext(x);
              }
            }
          },
          ex => { finished = true; observer.OnError(ex); },
          () => { finished = true; observer.OnCompleted(); }
        );
        return disposable;
      }
    );
  }

}
```

You then use it like this (`Evaluate` is your predicate and `n` is the number of items to pass through after the predicate matches):

```
changes.WhereThenTake(Evaluate, n).Subscribe( ... );
```

Comment: Great answer with added value! id pick it if you were first, but i hope upvote is still something :)